# Rxjs distinct and arrays of numbers

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I can't explain to myself this

```
const something = new Rx.BehaviorSubject([1,2,4,4])
.distinct()
.do((s) => console.log(s))
.map(list => list.length)
.filter(length => length >=2)
.subscribe(total => console.log('total:', total));
```

this is what I get as output

```
[1, 2, 4, 4]
"total:"
 4
```

I get confused because reviewing the docs on distinct I thought it would work for numbers.  My use case is a data table widget sends me events and this array tracks which row they clicked and I want to detect once a double click occurred.

updated code

```
const something = new Rx.BehaviorSubject([]);
```

something.next([1]);
console.log(something.getValue());
something.next(something.getValue().concat(2));
something.next(something.getValue().concat(3));
something.next(something.getValue().concat(4));
something.next(something.getValue().concat(4));

something
.distinct()
.subscribe(val => console.log('value:', val));

output

```
"value:"
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: You have stream of one array (not stream of numbers), distinct of one array is the same array :)

Comment: OH I can accept this as an answer that makes sense

Comment: @OlesSavluk what about the updated snippet I posted above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a value that happens to be an array. You would see the operation of distinct if you did

```
const something = new Rx.BehaviorSubject([]);
something .distinct() .subscribe(val => console.log('value:', val));
something.next(1); // --> value: 1
something.next(2); // --> value: 2
something.next(1); // no output (because of distinct)
something.next(3); // --> value: 3
```

Comment: How might you propose finding when duplicate value being sent in and maintaining knowledge of which ids have been submitted. Or is this not something I should be doing with rx? I wrote what I wanted to accomplish in plain js but now just curious if its possible and how might be able to do. So say sent in 1,2,4,6,2 ...then you would know 2 is duplicate

Comment: @Barry sounds like you want to create an operation that is the opposite of ```distinct```. Of course it is possible - just start with the code for ```distinct``` (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/distinct.js) and invert when it sends.  Specifically, [this line](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/distinct.js#L50) becomes ```! this._h.push(key) && this._o.onNext(x);``` ("when the key IS in the I've-seen-this-value hash, send it through.")

Comment: @Barry Of course, you want to use Rx only when you're looking at a stream of values over time. You set up subscriptions and handlers to do things in the future with values you have not yet seen. If you know your set of values right now, you don't need Rx. For instance, using UnderscoreJS, ```_.groupBy(mylist, _.identity).filter(function(g) { return g.length>1; }).flatten().uniq()```

Comment: gotcha yea these do occur over time as user browses table but in me playing with jsbin/rx I tried to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: thanks for both comments and answering my follow up I really appreciate it